# Textbox inside table td

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, word-wrap, css-tables

I've been working on a pyramid website and I'm having a problem. I have a `textbox` inside my `td`, and if the text is long, it cannot be seen already. Here is what it looks like:

[image]

As you can see the `level1` portion there, if I have a name like `someLongnameforever`, it will only be seen like this:

[image]

Is there a fix for this using css or any trick? I am using `bootstrap` by the way.

If you want to see my table code, click [this](http://pastebin.com/EPe3QLgt). I'm using `twig` templating also.

For now I am already using a `textarea` for the level 1 fields.

Comment: That depends, what do you want 'fixed'? Do you want the inputfield to expand or do you want to show more text only?

Comment: @Patrick2607 to show more or whatever is better

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `overflow: scroll;` to allow scrolling or you could add an ToolTip attribute so when users however they will see the full content.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try ellipsing if it exceeds the maximum width available to it. And maybe try showing the complete name in a tooltip?

That would keep the table clean too.

Comment: Tooltip is a nice idea. What ellipsing do you mean?

Comment: @FewFlyBy: Ellipsing meaning, try adding something like this  
.truncate {
  width: 250px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

So, if your test is something like "Hi, how are you?", then it might become something like, "Hi, how...", and then you can show the complete text in tooltip. :)

Comment: What really is not working? the ellipsising? or the tooltip?

Comment: so, that's a table-cell, right?? Let me give it a try, if thats the case.

Comment: A textbox inside a table-cell :)

Comment: @FewFlyBy: If all these are textboxes, then maybe u could do one thing. Place a label over input boxes. Whenever the user clicks on label, hide label, and show input, and whenever the user blurs out of input, hide input, and show the label.

Comment: See... I'll try giving an example...

<div style="position: relative">
 <label style=" position: absolute; z-index=2; background: #fff" on-click="this.hide()"> text is too long to be able to fit </label>
 <input type="text" on-blur="this.hide; this.sibling('label').show(); />
</div>

Did u get the idea?

Comment: Honestly, I don't get it :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88193/discussion-between-shivi-and-fewflyby).

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yousafzainasir9/a6x3u3qt/1/)wrap word to new line if there is overflow

```
button{ 
      word-wrap:break-word;
white-space: normal;
}
```

Comment: Because that's a button not a textbox

Comment: you should use textarea  then

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can do something like this.
You should be able to change the example to fit your needs.

**HTML**

```
<div id="fitin">
    <div>Lorem im Lorem im Lorem im Lorem im</div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
 $(function() {
        var $fitin = $('#fitin');
        var $fitindiv = $('#fitin div');

        $fitindiv.css('font-size', '1em');

        while( $fitindiv.height() > $fitin.height() ) {
            $fitindiv.css('font-size', (parseInt($fitindiv.css('font-size')) - 1) + "px" );
        }
    });
```

**CSS**

```
#fitin {
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 1em;
}
```

Check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MYSVL/3421/)

Comment: I would not want to read data from a table with different font sizes

Comment: I tried it in a table and it doesn't work as expected like on a div

Comment: @JuanMendes, neither would I, but given the problem that was all i could think of.

Comment: @FewFlyBy, i used an id instead of an class so maybe just checked that you changed that.

Comment: @FewFlyBy, can you give us a bit of html in a fidde?